# Wordpress cloned but frontend still displays http://old_wordpress_site

Tags: subdomains, clone-site

I have cloned my old_wordpress_site: files and db.
In the database I have replaced everything from "old_wordpress_site" into "new_wordpress_site".
Wp-config.php on the new site has been updated with the credentials of the new database.

The admin dashboard is on the new url.
However, when I click "visit site" in admin dashboard, the frontend initially displays the new url and than switches to the old url after half a second.

What am I missing here?
Could it be that the front-end website is still connecting to the old database? That would puzzle me because config.php has been set to the new database.

I am stuck for two days now. Any help is welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. From the way you describe it, it looks like WordPress is generating the right site, but the server is redirecting to the old site. You may need help from your hosting provider to sort this out.

Comment: Thanks. I will contact my hosting provider.